# add attributes to html element (using mvc and razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, attributes

i have a partial view like the following

```
@model BtImage

@{
    string attributes = "";
    foreach (string key in Model.Attributes.Keys)
    {
        string value = Model.Attributes[key]
        attributes += key + "=" + value + " ";
    }
}

<img @(attributes) src="edit.png" alt="" />
```

if every attributes value is one word than everything is ok

but if the value of any attribute has more than one word (for example title can be more than one word) the above code prints result like this

```
<img title="edit" news alt="" />
```

but i want

```
<img title="edit news" alt="" />
```

how should i achieve this.

Comment: You should add the quote yourself in the attribute string like this `attributes += key + "=\"" + value + "\"";`. Also I suggest to do `@Html.Raw(attributes)` to avoid some accidental encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As twearay said, it's the way you build your string that is wrong, also using string.Format helps you be able to read the code better. This will work (and look nice!)

```
@model BtImage

@{
    string attributes = "";
    foreach (string key in Model.Attributes.Keys)
    {
        string value = Model.Attributes[key];
        attributes += string.Format("{0}=\"{1}\" ", key, value);
    }
}

<img @Html.Raw(attributes) src="edit.png" alt="" />
```